# get admin order grid content block blank when enable https

Tags: magento-1.8, admin, grid, ssl, https

When enable ssl or https it gives blank content area.
have debug using this code from `index.php` `register_shutdown_function("fatal_handler");`

```
function fatal_handler() {
    $error = error_get_last();
    echo("<pre>");
    print_r($error);
}
```

and give error like

```
   Array
(
    [type] => 2
    [message] => vsprintf(): Too few arguments
    [file] => /var/www/host/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Translate.php
    [line] => 416
)
```

have check all translation file but nothing found.can anyone please guide me on this.

Comment: Did you check your log files? try enabling developer mode and setting `display_errors` to 1

Comment: got error from em_deleteorder module.when https enable it gives order grid blank done't know why this happen.